# PostgreSQL Stack Builder Installation Certificate verification problem on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation, proxy, postgis

I have downloaded and installed PostgreSQL 12 (64 bit) on a developer machine running Windows 10 Pro Education (64 bit).

When the installation came to the Stack Builder download application list step, an error occurred as follows:

> A certification verification problem was encountered whilst accessing https://www.postgresql.org/applications-v2.xml schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092013) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline. This means that the source download cannot be verified. It is recommended that you do not continue with the download as it may be coming from a site that is pretending to be the intended download site and may contain viruses or malware.

> Do you wish to continue?

I have tried to use Proxy servers referring to this answer. https://serverfault.com/questions/555125/postgresql-stack-builder-installation-proxy-setting-on-windows

I have also tried both solutions from that question. Still, I can not get the application list downloaded.

I want to install PostGIS. It seems the stack builder is safe and easy to use. What should I do to get the PostGIS installed?

Comment: Can you answer "yes" to the question and proceed?

Comment: I tried that. It did not work the same error showed up that "Couldn't access the URL 'https://www.postgresql.org/application-v2.xml'."

Comment: I solved this problem by using a vpn. I am in China so that the connection was not successful. jlz

Comment: In my case, I was over the VPN and when is disconnected from VPN it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `https://www.postgresql.org/applications-v2.html` link has some strong security. And it blocks some traffic. As @ay__ya has mentioned, in his case he made it work though VPN access. And in my case I was already behind the VPN and it was not working. So disabling VPN worked for me.

Comment: what about the same error w.o a VPN? I am getting that and have to VM or VPN adapters running.

Comment: I am currently not sure what all traffics are blocked by them, but yes as @ay__ya already mentioned it worked for him by enabling VPN. So we would have to find some working host IP this can be either direct or behind VPN.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to https://www.postgresql.org/applications-v2.html and save as a *.CER file the certificate of the the webpage.
2. Using "certmgr.msc" import the *.CER file into your local certificates repository to the Trusted People store or/and Enterprise Trust store.
3. Rerun Stack builder and retry download application list step.
   Should works now.

Comment: I'd love to try this, but the url does not exist anymore...

Comment: The url changed to https://www.postgresql.org/applications-v2.xml